# Macro for adding missing dates

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset that has data for 3 months, October - December (this is a quarterly report so months will change).

Below is an example of my data:

[image]

In the example, ALB and ANC only have data for October and December, respectively. I need to create a macro that adds a line for the missing months.

The macro should return the following:

```
ALB,102023,9,2,0,0,9,9,.22,8.78
ALB,112023,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
ALB,122023,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
ANC,102023,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
ANC,112023,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
ANC,122023,3,1,0,0,3,3,.11,2.89
```

When I run the code, I do not get those results. Below are my results:

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
Sub FormatData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim destWs As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim destRow As Long
    
    ' Set the destination worksheet
    Set destWs = Sheets.Add
    destWs.Name = "SubmissionForm" ' You can change the name if needed
    
    ' Loop through each worksheet in the workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name <> destWs.Name Then ' Exclude the destination sheet
            destRow = 1 ' Start from the first row in the destination sheet
            
            ' Find the last row with data in the current sheet
            lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            
            ' Loop through each row in the current sheet
            For i = 2 To lastRow ' Assuming data starts from the second row
            
                ' Format the data and write to the destination sheet
                destWs.Cells(destRow, 1).Value = "4493M"
                destWs.Cells(destRow, 2).Value = IIf(ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = "", 0, ws.Cells(i, 2).Value)
                destWs.Cells(destRow, 3).Value = Format(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value, "mmyyyy")
                destWs.Cells(destRow, 4).Value = IIf(ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = "", 0, ws.Cells(i, 3).Value)
                destWs.Cells(destRow, 5).Value = IIf(ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = "", 0, ws.Cells(i, 4).Value)
                destWs.Cells(destRow, 6).Value = IIf(ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = "", 0, ws.Cells(i, 5).Value)
                destWs.Cells(destRow, 7).Value = IIf(ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = "", 0, ws.Cells(i, 6).Value)
                destWs.Cells(destRow, 8).Value = IIf(ws.Cells(i, 7).Value = "", 0, ws.Cells(i, 7).Value)
                destWs.Cells(destRow, 9).Value = IIf(ws.Cells(i, 8).Value = "", 0, ws.Cells(i, 8).Value)
                destWs.Cells(destRow, 10).Value = IIf(ws.Cells(i, 9).Value = "", 0, ws.Cells(i, 9).Value)
                destWs.Cells(destRow, 11).Value = IIf(ws.Cells(i, 10).Value = "", 0, ws.Cells(i, 10).Value)
                
                destRow = destRow + 1 ' Move to the next row in the destination sheet
            Next i

        
        
                Else
                    ' If no data for the month, add a line with all values set to 0
                    destWs.Cells(destRow, 1).Value = "4493M"
                    destWs.Cells(destRow, 2).Value = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
                    destWs.Cells(destRow, 3).Value = Format(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value, "mmyyyy")
                    destWs.Cells(destRow, 4).Value = 0
                    destWs.Cells(destRow, 5).Value = 0
                    destWs.Cells(destRow, 6).Value = 0
                    destWs.Cells(destRow, 7).Value = 0
                    destWs.Cells(destRow, 8).Value = 0
                    destWs.Cells(destRow, 9).Value = 0
                    destWs.Cells(destRow, 10).Value = 0
                    destWs.Cells(destRow, 11).Value = 0
                    
                    destRow = destRow + 1 ' Move to the next row in the destination sheet
                      End If

    Next ws
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Processing data in arrays is more efficient than update cells one by one.

> Use two `Dictionary` objects to consolidate data

- `oDic1`: `Col2+Date` combination
- `oDic2`: the unique list of `Col2`

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, desSht As Worksheet
    Dim oDic1, oDic2, arrData, vKey, arrRes
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, endMth As Long
    Dim ColCnt As Long, sKey As String, sYr As String
    Dim lastRow As Long, iRow As Long
    Const SHT_NAME = "SubmissionForm"
    Const COL_A = "4493M"
    Const NEW_DAY = "20"
    ' Creat or clear output sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set desSht = Sheets(SHT_NAME)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If desSht Is Nothing Then
        Set desSht = Sheets.Add
        desSht.Name = SHT_NAME
    Else
        desSht.Cells.Clear
    End If
    Set oDic1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set oDic2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Loop through worksheets
    For Each srcSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If srcSht.Name <> SHT_NAME Then
            ' Load data
            arrData = srcSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
            ColCnt = UBound(arrData, 2)
            If UBound(arrData) > 1 Then
                If IsDate(arrData(2, 1)) Then
                    ' the current year
                    sYr = Right(CStr(Year(arrData(2, 1))), 2)
                    ' the last month of the qtr
                    endMth = ((Month(arrData(2, 1)) + 2) \ 3) * 3
                    oDic1.RemoveAll
                    oDic2.RemoveAll
                    ' Loop through data
                    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
                        vKey = arrData(i, 2)
                        If Not oDic2.exists(vKey) Then
                            ' Unique list of Col2
                            oDic2(vKey) = ""
                            ' Unique list of Col2 & mth combination
                            For j = endMth - 2 To endMth
                                sKey = vKey & "|" & j
                                oDic1(sKey) = 0
                            Next
                        End If
                        sKey = arrData(i, 2) & "|" & Month(arrData(i, 1))
                        If oDic1.exists(sKey) Then oDic1(sKey) = i
                    Next i
                    ReDim arrRes(1 To oDic1.Count, 1 To ColCnt + 1)
                    i = 1
                    ' Populate the output array arrRes
                    For Each vKey In oDic1.Keys
                        arrRes(i, 1) = COL_A
                        arrRes(i, 2) = Split(vKey, "|")(0)
                        arrRes(i, 3) = Split(vKey, "|")(1) & NEW_DAY & sYr
                        iRow = oDic1(vKey)
                        If iRow = 0 Then
                            For j = 3 To ColCnt
                                arrRes(i, j + 1) = 0
                            Next j
                        Else
                            For j = 3 To ColCnt
                                arrRes(i, j + 1) = arrData(iRow, j)
                            Next j
                        End If
                        i = i + 1
                    Next
                End If
            End If
            ' Write output to sheet
            lastRow = desSht.Cells(desSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If lastRow > 1 Or Len(desSht.Cells(lastRow, 1)) > 0 Then lastRow = lastRow + 1
            desSht.Cells(lastRow, 1).Resize(UBound(arrRes), UBound(arrRes, 2)).Value = arrRes
        End If
    Next
    Dim c As Range
    ' Fill blank
    Set c = desSht.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then c.Value = 0
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: The second picture you provided does not include the results from Col3 in the first picture. The code also needs to make any blanks into 0s as well. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: The output matches `The macro should return the following` in your post.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I edited my question. Please see the results the macro should return.

Comment: Hello,

I would like to exclude Col7 and Col8 in the macro. Could you assist in editing the macro?

Comment: [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)